# Alternative to Sleep()

Tags: php, sonarqube

I'm trying to fetch data from an API but if the connection fails, I sleep for a few seconds and tries again. The problem is that SonarQube advices not to use `sleep()`:

> sleep is sometimes used in a mistaken attempt to prevent Denial of
>   Service (DoS) attacks by throttling response rate. But because it ties
>   up a thread, each request takes longer to serve that it otherwise
>   would, making the application more vulnerable to DoS attacks, rather
>   than less.

I can't seem to find any alternatives to delay a function. Should I just disable that SonarQube issue?

Comment: You could use [a cron/the crontab command](https://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) to run a specific php-script on a regular interval..

Comment: If only authorized users can initiate the script, then sleep should be fine. You're using sleep in order not to overload the API server you're calling, which is the right way to do it in my opinion. The warning is about DoS attacks where someone hits that script hundreds or thousands of times in a row to basically break your server. That risk can be mitigated by making sure only you (or an authorized user or your cron) can initiate the script

Comment: Depending on your situation, you could call your PHP function that makes the API call from JavaScript (ajax) and if it fails, return a "failed" status and have JavaScript retry the call after a delay. This way you wouldn't be tying up the server.

Comment: I have had to deal with a similar situation, and went for the queue approach. In my case I used https://github.com/JouwWeb/SlmQueue, which has a retry option. I sent a new job into the queue to process something with the API. If it failed, a new job was queued to retry in X minutes.
It worked really wel for my case, where some important stuff had to be synced using a very unstable remote API.